# Unable to override activeEnvironment in SOAPUI using maven pom

Tags: java, maven, soapui, pom.xml

I am trying to override the activeEnvironment property of my SoapUI project from maven pom file.

```
<configuration>
<projectFile>....</projectFile>
<property>
  <name>activeEnvironment</name>
  <value>X_Sprint</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

I am using soapUI pro and maven soapui plugin 5.0.0. Can some one suggest me if there is any wrong in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html#6-Full-Example) says the configuration should be:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            ...
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                        <projectProperties>
                            <value>message=Hello World!</value>
                        </projectProperties>
                    </configuration>
        </plugin>
```